# Mesh for 3d dungeons game.

Tags: real-analysis

Hallo, I look for some F: R^2->R height function which would generate the Speleothem ceiling http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speleothem for 3d game taking place in dungeons/caves. 
The function might be in any form usable for generating mesh.

Comment: This seems like an interesting question. However, perhaps depending on what preciely you look for, this is not the optimal site to ask it; there is AFAIK also a stackexchange site on game developpin for example. Still, I would like to see the question stay open here (at least for a while). Perhaps you could add some more details in the meantime. 

Comment: I think this is off-topic. But for what it is worth, you'd probably be better off looking not for a fixed height function, but for something generated using something like `context free` http://www.contextfreeart.org/index.html or with similar design philosophy and tune your parameters. You may also want to track down the original paper mentioned in http://news.sciencemag.org/sciencenow/2005/01/18-03.html to see how cave formations are mathematically modeled. 

Comment: I voted to reopen. IMO, this question on rocks is considerably more on-topic than the recent one on rooks. 

Comment: Agree with quid. As probable answer I would try 2D LEVI flightts whatever it means.
